# swipejs looks alike Android native view component

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an Android app natively and my client requested me to add a sliding bannar used to be on mobile websites with JQuery Mobile and http://swipejs.com/.

Is there any native equivalent Views (or component?) that display images and slide them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) - finger-oriented view container. It was introduced in API level 11 but also available through [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/extras/support-library.html). Also you may look to [ImageSwitcher](http://alotaboutandroid.blogspot.com/2012/04/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html)